# Trouble opening and closing a div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```css
.box-one {
  border: 0.1em solid #ccc;
 }

.dropdown-info {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-one">
  <div class="header">
    <h3 class="text-center">Sample Header</h3>
   </div>
  <div class="dropdown-info">
    <p class="text-center">Sample Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to open and close a div if another div is clicked on and I tried with both .toggle() and .click() but it won't work. I would like to get someone else's opinion on it. I will show how I tried accomplishing it using both methods

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var descriptionOpen = false;

    if (descriptionOpen === false) {
        $('.header').click(function() {
            $('.dropdown-info').show();
            descriptionOpen === true;
        });
    };
    else if (descriptionOpen === true) {
        $('.header').click(function() {
            $('.dropdown-info').hide();
            descriptionOpen === false;
        });
    };
});


$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.header').toggle(function() {
        ('.dropdown-info').show();
    }, function() {
        ('.dropdown-info').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code snippets are missing their HTML. The point of being able to provide live code examples is to demonstrate the problem. By not including the HTML you demonstrate a completely different problem.

Comment: I suspect that they were a result of misunderstanding the toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this:

```
$('.header').click(function() {
    $('.dropdown-info').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Wow thats so simple I never thought of it like that. Thank you very much.